# Why babelConfig not working in webpack encore?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-encore

I want to add support for async / await functions for my project.

I install

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
```

It's my `webpack.config.js`

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build')

    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

    .enableBuildNotifications()

    .enableVueLoader()

    .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
       babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-env');
       babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-stage-2');
       babelConfig.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-transform-runtime');
    })

;

const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

config.externals = {

    mode: 'development',
    // global app config object
    config: JSON.stringify({
        apiUrl: 'http://localhost:80',
        devServer: {
            public: 'http://localhost:3000',
            disableHostCheck: true,
        },
    })
};

config.node = {
    fs: "empty"
};


module.exports = config;
```

When I run a server dev, I get an error.

```
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Duplicate plugin/preset detected.
If you'd like to use two separate instances of a plugin,
they need separate names, e.g.

  plugins: [
    ['some-plugin', {}],
    ['some-plugin', {}, 'some unique name'],
  ]
```

I can not understand what the problem is.

I also created a .babelrc file and wrote the same configuration in it. But unfortunately, this did not help (

Comment: which version of babel are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.babelrc` for change babel config like this. This file should be in your project root

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      ...
    ],
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then remove this from your `webpack.config.js`

```
.configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
   babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-env');
   babelConfig.presets.push('@babel/preset-stage-2');
   babelConfig.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-transform-runtime');
})
```

Comment: If the Babel version is more than 7, then the preset should not be used.
``` .configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.plugins = ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
            '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'];
    })```

Comment: @Alexandr You can use presets event if Babel version is more than 7. I'm using Babel 7 with preset and Webpack Encore and everything work well.